# Searching for words in a sentence with c# in the database

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I am trying to write a desktop program using c# and visual sutdio. What I want to do in the program; searching inside a column of the database table I have and sorting the records that match it. I want to do the search criteria with the like command, for example, in the patient name table in the hospital database, sort those whose name contains the letters ABC. I want this

```
(Select *from patient where patient_name like'" + comboBox1.Text + "')
```

value to be a rule that I set, not from combobox. I want to do a search like

```
(Select *from patient where patient_name like '"+ ABC+"')
```

I will give an example to explain my problem more clearly, I want to use this command, which works in Access, in visual studio.

```
select patient_name from patient where patient_name like '*abc*';
```

How can I do this in visual studio?

Comment: `%` is the equivalent wildcard character if you are using MS SQL Server. This is not related to Visual Studio.

Comment: You *must* parameterize your statement, otherwise you are open to **dangerous** SQL injection. Then you simply do `select patient_name from patient where patient_name like '%' + @searchParam + '%';`

Comment: ı tried this but the query is not working as i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string 
PatientName = "abc";
        public void fill_combobox()
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Patient_name from Patient where Patient_name like  '%" + @PatientName + "%' and patient_old='3'  ", connection);
            OleDbDataReader data = komut.ExecuteReader();
            while (data.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(data[0]);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If you think that is using a parameter, it is not. That is just a variable that starts with @. If you are connecting to MSSQL then oledb is not the preferred provider. Finally, you should dispose the Command and Reader.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from patient where patient_name like '%" + textbox1.Text + "%';
```